# Elasticsearch 6.2.3 crashing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We are experiencing some strange behaviours in elasticsearch 6.2.3 version.

Scenario:

When we do a full text search with certain 12 digit numbers (xxxxxxxxxxxx), the elasticsearch process die and also kibana timed out. The strange thing is the search on most number works fine but we have a number when that is used everything crash.

As note, the heap size also blows up.

> [ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [xxxxxxxx] fatal error in thread [Thread-5], exiting
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> [ERROR][o.e.t.n.Netty4Utils      ] fatal error on the network layer
>           at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.maybeDie(Netty4Utils.java:184)